# Function not called when clicking on a button in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am building a BMR calculator with radio buttons for Male and Female.
I am using a switch case to calculate BMR for each but it doesn't seem to work.

Nothing happens when I press the calculate button.
It seems to work okay when I calculate it directly i.e without switch case, the ResultTextView becomes visible and shows the answers. I apologize if I am repeating the question, I am new to programming. Please ignore the formulae for BMR I know they aren't correct I just put them for testing. 
    Following is my code:

```java
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class BmrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton bmrFemaleRadioButton;
        RadioButton bmrMaleRadioButton;

        EditText bmrAgeEditText;
        EditText bmrWeightEditText;
        EditText bmrHeightEditText;
        Button bmrCalculateButton;
        TextView bmrResultTextView;

        Double age;
        Double weight;
        Double height;
        Double resultBmr;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmr);

            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            bmrFemaleRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.bmrFemaleRadioButton);
            bmrMaleRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.bmrMaleRadioButton);

            bmrAgeEditText = findViewById(R.id.bmrAgeEditText);
            bmrWeightEditText = findViewById(R.id.bmrWeightEditText);
            bmrHeightEditText = findViewById(R.id.bmrHeightEditText);
            bmrCalculateButton = findViewById(R.id.bmrCalculateButton);
            bmrResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.bmrResultTextView);

            bmrFemaleRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bmrAgeEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrWeightEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrHeightEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrCalculateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            bmrMaleRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bmrAgeEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrWeightEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrHeightEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bmrCalculateButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

        public void calculateBmr(final View view){
            age = Double.parseDouble(bmrAgeEditText.getText().toString());
            weight = Double.parseDouble(bmrWeightEditText.getText().toString());
            height = Double.parseDouble(bmrHeightEditText.getText().toString());

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId){
                        case R.id.bmrFemaleRadioButton:
                            resultBmr = age + weight + height;
                            bmrResultTextView.setText("Your BMR is "+resultBmr);
                            bmrResultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case R.id.bmrMaleRadioButton:
                            resultBmr = age * weight * height;
                            bmrResultTextView.setText("Your BMR is "+resultBmr);
                            bmrResultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Following is my XML layout file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".BmrActivity">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/bmrFemaleRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:text="Female" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/bmrMaleRadioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:text="Male" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bmrAgeEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your age"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bmrWeightEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your weight in kgs"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bmrAgeEditText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/bmrHeightEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your height in cms"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bmrWeightEditText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bmrCalculateButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="calculateBmr"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bmrHeightEditText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bmrResultTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="Answer"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bmrCalculateButton" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You are calling `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` when the button has been clicked, but by that time the radio button has already been checked. The `onCheckedChange()` is called when the change occurs.
Instead of setting a listener, you can directly get the checked item id by calling `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`

like this

```
switch(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    case R.id.bmrFemaleRadioButton:
         resultBmr = age + weight + height;
         bmrResultTextView.setText("Your BMR is "+resultBmr);
         bmrResultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         break;
    case R.id.bmrMaleRadioButton:
         resultBmr = age * weight * height;
         bmrResultTextView.setText("Your BMR is "+resultBmr);
         bmrResultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         break;
}
```

Comment: @Annek If your problem has been cleared, accept Ismail Shaikh's answer to finish this Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try move get age, weight, height inside onCheckChanged. Because it only parse one time and not update again.

Comment: Yes, thanks I didn't think of that. Now it works as I put in the braces for the switch case but resultTextView becomes visible only when I change radio buttons.

Comment: Add condition find checked checkbox by id follow your below answer